# Stability of hydrosols given temperature and humidity

Tags: thermodynamics, water

I had always been under the impression that animal exhalations were composed of air, carbon dioxide, and water vapor, meaning individual molecules of H2O in the form of a gas.

However, recently I read [a paper which claimed that exhalations may contain hydrosols](https://respiratory-research.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12931-019-0970-9) (aerosols of water) consisting of small spheres of water between 1 and 100 micrometers in diameter. By comparison a typical particle of pollen is about 100 micrometers in size. This paper did not actually claim proof of this, just speculations and a summary of various experiments done over the years to try to prove the existence of such aerosols and determine their size. The authors of the paper say it is "difficult" to do this.

Rather than muddle through these various inconclusive experiments, I am curious whether physics can answer the question as to the existence and stability of these supposed aerosols.

As a pilot, I find it hard to believe that such aerosols exist. The reason is that pilots are taught that most water in the atmosphere is a vapor and that only when it rises to a cooler layer in the sky does it turn into a cloud and become an aerosol, whereupon it becomes visible. One example given to us to explain this is that when a person breathes on a cold day, the water vapor exhaled condenses to form an aerosol just like a cloud forms in the sky. Both are dependent on the dewpoint.

So, this understanding would conflict with the suppositions of the linked paper which seems to be claiming that invisible hydrosols form from exhalations regardless of dewpoint. From the standpoint of physics, is this a supportable idea?